# Calculate color of an Pixel for a transparent application background image

Tags: vb.net, math, colors, formula, pixel

I use VB for my application and have a rounded Background Image including logo. Its also a bit anisotropic anisalized to prevent a sharp Logo. Because vb only allows color key-ing without any tolerance I have to replace the pixels with an Alpha value to an Pixel without one. In a nutshell I have to combine the Pixel of the screen with the Pixel of the background image. But the Problem is: I don't know the formula to get the result color of the Pixel.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand your question, all you're asking is for an equation that gives the resulting pixel color based on the combination of a translucent image over an opaque background/screen?

Comment: @WillB Yes. That's all What i ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "Alpha Compositing" You can use the following equations, courtesy of the wikipedia page ([click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)), to get the resulting RGB values from two transparent RGB images. (only one has to be transparent, so the other one can be your screen/background with 100% alpha.)

These equations assume that you have one transparent object on top of another object, where R1 is the Red component of object #1, a1 is the alpha of object #1, and so on and so forth...

I'll show the highlights below

```
R = (R1 * a1 / 255) + (R2 * a2 * (255 - a1) / (255^2))
G = (G1 * a1 / 255) + (G2 * a2 * (255 - a1) / (255^2))
B = (B1 * a1 / 255) + (B2 * a2 * (255 - a1) / (255^2))
Alpha = a1 + (a2 * (255 - a1) / 255)
```

I also recommend skimming the wiki page because it's quite fascinating.